# Vertical align is not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to centre a few images in their divs, but somehow vertical align isn't working. In the snippet  `d-flex justify-content-end` and `text-center` aren't working either, but the icons are supposed to be next to each other. I want the icons to be in the center of their div, I used `align-items-center` to achieve this effect, but the icons are staying within the top center of their div instead. Am I missing something? On getbootstrap it only says to use it with d-flex, which I did.

```css
/*    .navicons {
    float: right !important
} */

.iconwrap {
 width: 100%;
    min-heigh: 35px;
/*  position: relative; */
}

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #7dc623;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
/*  align-items: center; */
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #ffffff;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
/* align-items: center; */
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
 opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
 opacity: 0;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 navicons">
      <div class="text-center iconwrap d-flex justify-content-end">
       <div class="d-inline-block navicons1 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif" alt="account"/></div>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline-block navicons2 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif" alt="favorieten"/></div>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline-block navicons3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif" alt="winkelmandje"/></div>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/DZxP59y.gif" alt="winkelmandje"/></a>
       </div>
       </div>        
     </div>
         </div>
```

edit: I also tried it with the following code, but same effect, it stays at the top left

```css
.navicons {
 float: right !important;
}
.iconwrap {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 35px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #7dc623;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
 align-items: center; 
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #ffffff;
 opacity: 1;
 position: absolute;
 align-items: center;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 10;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
 opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
 opacity: 0;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 navicons">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center iconwrap">
      <div class="d-inline-block float-right navicons1">
       <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif" alt="account"/></div>
          <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline-block float-right navicons2">
        <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif" alt="favorieten"/></div>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline-block float-right navicons3">
        <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif" alt="winkelmandje"/></div>
         <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/DZxP59y.gif" alt="winkelmandje"/></a>
       </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: This is how I learned it in my course, but duly noted.

Comment: you are using `justify-content-end`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need the div's to be at the right of the row, and even if I remove `justify-content-end` and use `float-right` the icons are still not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. The icons are centred by using `justify-content-center` and `align-items-center`.

```css
/*    .navicons {
    float: right !important
} */

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-heigh: 35px;
  /*  position: relative; */
}

.navicons1,
.navicons2,
.navicons3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  /*  align-items: center; */
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1,
.naviconshov2,
.naviconshov3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  /* align-items: center; */
  /*top: 0;*/
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 navicons">
    <div class="text-center iconwrap d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="d-inline-block navicons1 d-flex justify-content-center  align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif" alt="account" /></div>
        <a href="index.html"><img class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="d-inline-block navicons2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov2 d-flex justify-content-center  align-items-center"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif" alt="favorieten" /></div>
        <a href="index.html"><img class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="d-inline-block navicons3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="naviconshov3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"><img  src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif" alt="winkelmandje" /></div>
        <a href="index.html"><img class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/DZxP59y.gif" alt="winkelmandje" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not center the hover icon, I need both to be centered.

Comment: have you run the code snippet? It does center the hover icon.

Comment: I did, and when you hover it slightly moves down.

Comment: Hi, can you please check again. I have updated the code for the img tag. e.g. `<img class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" src="https://i.imgur.com/DZxP59y.gif" alt="winkelmandje" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

to the div with class naviconshov1,naviconshov2 etc  .

```
<div class="naviconshov1">
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, the icons are still in the top left in their div.

Comment: Hello. You have 2 styles defined for .navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 { } .
Pl make sure that you add these styles to the latter one.